# Are there guidelines for what code goes into com.myproject.api vs com.myproject.api.impl?

Tags: android, api, package, structure

I've seen this package structure pattern a number of times.  Most recently, I've been going through the Last.fm Android app code and would like to understand why some code is in fm.last.api versus fm.last.api.impl.
https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/

Answer (score 1):

The package `fm.last.api`contains the interfaces that define the public interface. In the package `fm.last.api.impl` the actual implementation of this interface is located.

This is a rarely widely used approach to differentiate various concerns.

Comment: When you say "interfaces", are you using the term loosely?  Or do you mean actual interfaces, as opposed to classes.  I ask because `fm.last.api` contains interfaces as well as classes.  That's what actually threw me off to begin with.

Comment: Generally I was talking about actual interfaces, but maybe there can be also other necessary classes like exceptions. But I had just another look at your example, and I can find the package fm.last.api.impl neither can I find any interfaces or classes at all: https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/tree/master/app/src/fm/last/api

Comment: The packages are actually in the library project  - [link](https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/tree/master/library/src/fm/last/api)